# Is there any basic MICR stock check printing software without any frills or gimmicks?

Tags: offline, finance, printing

I am looking for a basic piece of software that does ONE job and as little else as possible. I have completely blank generic brand check stock that needs to have the MICR code line and other basic account data and formatting lines printed to make what Quickbooks expects as blank checks.

I used to use an old Version of VersaCheck that did just this, but it won't run on newer versions of Windows<sup>1</sup>. The newer versions are out of the question because they require use of either a verification service or a per check fee. Their free version also only works if you buy their branded check stock and use the codes off of each package to print just that many checks.

I have tried downloading some other software but haven't found any that meet even a majority of this criteria:

Let's start with the positives:

- I *do* need it to know a couple basic check stock sizes (any sizes based on popularly available Letter based sheet stock is fine) and to know how to lay the check out so that Quickbooks can then print the actual check content.
- I *do* need it to remember/save the account numbers and details for a handful of different accounts.
- I *do* need this software to install and run in a completely offline environment.

But the problem I'm trying to solve is riddled with negative criteria:

- I *don't* want it to do everything like keep a register, balance my account and clean the kitchen.
- I *don't* need it to import or export data.
- I *don't* need it to "print checks", **only to change blank stock into blank checks** by adding the MICR line and other basic formatting.
- I *don't* want to be locked to a specific brand of stock or to any verification services or ongoing fees.
- I *don't* want adware or other nonsense. Changing my browser settings is a disqualifier.

Lastly there are a couple of non criteria:

- I *don't care* about the platform. I use Linux and would prefer that, but don't expect to find it. Quickbooks is running in a virtual machine with Windows 7 and I am ok with installing something there.
- I *would prefer* gratis but would be willing to pay a small fee (<$30 or so) to have this problem out of my hair if a piece of software otherwise meets all the criteria. I'm not going to pay $150 for something that syncs my account data via some corporate phone-home mechanism while changing the baby's diapers to keep me distracted.

I have the issue of the MICR line needing to be printed with magnetic ink covered if some program will just send the line to my printer.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The last version that did what I need without gimmicks won't run past Windows XP. Predictably now that XP is EOL'ed, the VM I run it in has <strike>caught a cold</strike> become virus infested and I am trying to build a new platform on a maintainable version of Windows.</sub>

Comment: Checks in what format? (What country, what bank if relevant?)

Comment: @Gilles Already in my question, but US formats (there are 2 very common and a few assorted formats that come in Letter size sheets at every office supply store in the country. I don't really care as long as QB supports a matched set and I can find the stock cheap, which again is not the limiting factor here.

Comment: My current stock is "versacheck form 3000 prestige", but I don't think it matters as the overall blank check material size / cutout on the page is the same across a bunch of brands.

Comment: Is there some rational way to get QuickBooks to do this? I would have thought this was a feature they'd support.

Comment: Another thought: Can you build an XP VM just for running VersaCheck? I presume that you've got an appropriate XP license, so if you did a minimal XP install into a VM (don't even bother with network drivers), might you be able to get VersaCheck working there?

Comment: @MichaelKohne I thought the same thing; doing this straight from QuickBooks makes the most sence. To date I can't find a way to do it and their website specifically says you need a separate program to print the MICR line. I suspect they have a contract with some check company to keep the feature out of the program, but that's just my conspiracy theory.

Comment: @Caleb - re:Quickbooks - it may actually be less nefarious that that - if there's any kind of certification of the printing equipment or software, they might not want to spend the bucks on doing so for a limited use feature.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Judging from the number of companies with products out there just for this feature, it is not a limited use feature.

Comment: "Predictably now that XP is EOL'ed, the VM I run it in has become virus infested" That is not predictable at all. There is no reason you cannot build and maintain an XP VM securely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sometime circa about a month after I posted this question to the present I've been using `freecheck` to print blank checks. In fact I downloaded the tarball source releases and reposted [them on GitHub](https://github.com/alerque/freecheck) for easier access and checking what changed between releases. The config file for setting it up is a bit arcane but one you work out the values and your layout it just works. And works. And works.

Answer (score 5):

I used to use VersaCheck until they turned into ransomware.

After a stressful couple of weeks looking for a replacement I ended up with [ezCheckPrinting](http://www.halfpricesoft.com/business-blog/category/ezCheckPrinting.aspx)

I purchased a license for $39 and I've been using it probably about 2 years without complaint. I usually look pretty hard for free software but I believe this purchase was worth the money. There are no weirdo extra fees and you can use any blank check stock.

I print on completely blank check stock and make blank checks for quickbooks and I also print filled out check drafts with it so people pay can me via phone etc. (which is awesome and was one of the main features I was looking for).

It does have register functions and I think a couple other features that I don't use and are easily ignored and the software doesn't feel bloated at all. If you're just printing blank quickbooks checks I don't think you even see the register stuff.

The interface look/feel is pretty dated but so were most of the ones I looked at. The usability is maybe a little better than average although it is a little clunky, but once it's set up and you use it a couple of times that doesn't matter much anymore.

Edit: Also I never bothered with magnetic ink and I've never had a bank refuse a check in at least 6 or 7 years. I had one vendor with a really old machine that couldn't read them but they just assumed it was a fluke and deposited to their bank like any other check and it went through fine. So depending who you're writing checks to you might not need the magnetic stuff any more.

Answer (score 1):

I rely on  [check writing software](http://checkwritingsoftware.net/).
Pros:

- Offers ease in usage
- Fairly easy and quick.
- Less complicated.
- Multiple function.

Answer (score 1):

I use Print Checks Pro.
It allow for the use of all standard formats and paper, isn't expensive, is a one-time purchase with no mandatory upgrades or time limits and is easy to set up and use.
The only real drawbacks are - you have to design your checks on their built in check designer, either business or personal, and it does have a register function.

Aside from those two problems, I have found it quite good.
Price is about $40.00